# Start rolling sum from 0 at reaching specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, rolling-computation

In SQL Server version 18.11.1, I have a challenge that I cannot solve at the moment.

I have a column with values like:

| ID | Value | Counters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 10 | 1 |
| 11 | 1 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 13 | 1 | 1 |
| 14 | 1 | 1 |
| 15 | 3 | 1 |

What I am trying to do is a rolling sum that would restart after hitting 10 or more in rolling sum value or when rolling sum of counters would become more than 3

Expectation

| Value | Rolling_Sum | Rolling_Counter_Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | 2 |
| 1 | 8 | 3 --restart trigger hit |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 9 | 2 |
| 6 | 15 --restart trigger hit | 3 |
| 7 | 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 15 --restart trigger hit | 2 |
| 9 | 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 19 --restart trigger hit | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 --restart as trigger hit |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |

I have tried everything I could imagine and read a lot of open topics already but could not find the solution. Please help.

I was thinking about using unbound preceding and current row but cannot think of way restarting it at hitting the trigger.

Comment: The row with Value=10 should have expected Rollling_sum=19, shouldn't it? Also there should be another column defining order of rows. Then recursive-query-based solution will help. I doubt it is solvable purely using window functions since each island depends on the previous.

Comment: Look into `recursive cte`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you already have a column that defines the order of rows. This is possible with [`recursive cte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) :

```
WITH cte (id, val, Rolling_Sum, Rolling_Counter_Sum) AS
(
    SELECT id, val, val AS Rolling_Sum, Counters as Rolling_Counter_Sum
    FROM mytable
    WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.id, e.val, 
           case when d.Rolling_Sum < 10 and d.Rolling_Counter_Sum < 3
                then d.Rolling_Sum else 0 
           end + e.val,
           case when d.Rolling_Sum < 10 and d.Rolling_Counter_Sum < 3
                then d.Rolling_Counter_Sum else 0 
           end + e.Counters
    FROM mytable AS e
        INNER JOIN cte AS d
        ON e.id = d.id+1
    
)
SELECT id, Rolling_Sum, Rolling_Counter_Sum
from cte
```

Result :

| id | Rolling_Sum | Rolling_Counter_Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 7 | 2 |
| 3 | 8 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 9 | 2 |
| 6 | 15 | 3 |
| 7 | 7 | 1 |
| 8 | 15 | 2 |
| 9 | 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 19 | 2 |
| 11 | 1 | 1 |
| 12 | 2 | 2 |
| 13 | 3 | 3 |
| 14 | 1 | 1 |
| 15 | 4 | 2 |

This recursive query calculates a rolling sum by adding values from the "val" column of each row until the rolling sum reaches 10. Once the rolling sum exceeds 10, it resets to 0 for subsequent rows. The query starts with an initial row where id equals 1 and performs the recursive calculation by joining the rows with consecutive ids.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/hfA0jEOl)

Comment: That got potential to my actual issue. Would you please explain how that works?

What I am actually trying to achieve is restart rolling sum when one of two conditions.

Comment: I have added some explanations, I hope it helps

Comment: I thought it would be easier, so I simplified my question first, but I have updated it, if you could help on that I will really appreciate that. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: That is great! Thank you so much. I will now try to understand how it actually works.

Comment: To make query more robust, I would personally prefer computing `Rolling_Counter_Sum` as `case ... + e.Counters` instead of `+ 1` (since specification talks only about sum of value 3, not that there are only `1` values). Also the join `ON e.id = d.id+1` relies on continuous `ID` sequence hence if it does not hold (or if `ID`s were actually timestamps), precomputation of auxiliar column as `row_number() over (order by id)` would be handy. Anyway, nice answer @SelVazi, I upvoted it.

Comment: Good remarks @TomášZáluský I have edited my answer to use `Counters`  column instead of `1` , and if IDs are not continuously created or are timestamps, an additional column is required.

Comment: Thank you @SelVazi and Tomáš Záluský.

You have already helped a lot. One more question I got. Would it also be possible to make all rows be grouped based on reset. For example, all rows before and including reset row to be group 1, then all rows after first reset and before second (included) to be group 2 etc.?

Comment: Think I have achieved it by adding one more column: "Id as Groups" and adding one more condition:

"case when d.Rolling_Sum >= 10 or d.Rolling_Counter_Sum >= 3
           then d.groups else 0 end + d.groups"

Comment: "case when d.Rolling_Sum >= 10 or d.Rolling_Counter_Sum >= 3 then 1 else 0 end + d.groups"